# Failure creating document in Matter Centric HP/Autonomy WorkSite (iManage) DMS

Tags: imanage, worksite-sdk

I'm trying to create a document in the DMS, set some attributes, then check it in.  This worked great until we disallowed flat-space filing.  Now I have to specify a workspace folder before I can save, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.

```
lcDoc = mcDatabase.CreateDocument()
lcDoc.Security.DefaultVisibility = imSecurityType.imView
lcDoc.Security.GroupACLs.Add("INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY", imAccessRight.imRightAll)
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileDescription, FileName)
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileAuthor, msUserID)
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileOperator, msUserID)
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileType, "ANSI")
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileClass, "ADMIN")
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom1, ClientID)
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom2, MatterID)
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom10, "060")
lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom14, DMSServerName)        

' Fails here with error: [Folder ][AddDocument ]Operation requested on a record that     does not exist.
DirectCast(loFolder, NRTFolder).AddDocument(DirectCast(lcDoc, NRTDocument))

' If I comment out the line above, this line returns a failure:
' This operation is currently not available due to flatspace filing restrictions.
Dim lcResults As IManCheckinResult = lcDoc.CheckInWithResults(lsFilePath,     imCheckinDisposition.imCheckinNewDocument, imCheckinOptions.imDontKeepCheckedOut)
```

I'm struggling to find the right API document that gives this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the solution was on an interface I didn't know about, but found the COM developer's guide on page 81.

```
        lcDoc = mcDatabase.CreateDocument()
        'lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileLocation, loFolder.ObjectID)
        lcDoc.Security.DefaultVisibility = imSecurityType.imView
        lcDoc.Security.GroupACLs.Add("APPLICATIONSDEVELOPMENTALL", imAccessRight.imRightAll)
        lcDoc.Security.GroupACLs.Add("INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY", imAccessRight.imRightAll)
        ' [04/21/2014 KB] Changed this to use the specified name instead of a hard coded one.

        ' lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileDescription, String.Format("iManageAPI:{0}", "Test Create Document"))
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileDescription, FileName)
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileAuthor, msUserID)
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileOperator, msUserID)
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileType, "ANSI")
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileClass, "ADMIN")
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom1, ClientID)
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom2, MatterID)
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom10, "060")
        lcDoc.Profile.SetAttributeByID(imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom14, DMSServerName)
        ''loFolder.AddDocument(lcDoc) 'Add document to folder
        'DirectCast(loFolder, NRTFolder).AddDocument(DirectCast(lcDoc, NRTDocument))
        'Dim lcResults As IManCheckinResult = lcDoc.CheckInWithResults(lsFilePath, imCheckinDisposition.imCheckinNewDocument, imCheckinOptions.imDontKeepCheckedOut)
        lcResults = DirectCast(lcDoc, IManDocument3).
            CheckInExToFolderAsNewDocumentWithResults(lsFilePath, imCheckinOptions.imDontKeepCheckedOut, loFolder,
                                                      imHistEvent.imHistoryNew,
                                                      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                                                      "", "")
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have been killing myself with talking to HP for two weeks to obtain another copy of the COM developers guide...is there any chance you could send it? Thanks.

Comment: My email is jernej.goricki@gmail.com. THANKS A LOT!